# How do I disable keyboard and mouse entry for a JSpinner?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

When I try to make a JSpinner un-editable by keyboard or mouse like this:

```
((DefaultEditor) mySpinner.getEditor()).getTextField().setEditable(false);
mySpinner.setEnabled(false);
```

It disables any keyboard entry and pasting, but I can still click the up/down buttons and change the value.

How do I disable the up/down buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the spinner uses a JSpinner.DefaultEditor or its subclass, then the following code works (keyboard navigation disabled, spinner buttons do not work, yet it is possible to select and copy the value displayed in the spinner).

```
JSpinner component = ...;

component.setEnabled( false );
if ( component.getEditor() instanceof JSpinner.DefaultEditor ) {
   JSpinner.DefaultEditor editor = ( JSpinner.DefaultEditor ) component.getEditor();
   editor.getTextField().setEnabled( true );
   editor.getTextField().setEditable( false );
}
```

If the spinner has a custom editor with something other then JTextComponent, then it is probably still possible to use the same approach (disable the spinner, re-enable the actual component used by the spinner editor, mark that component as read-only using its API).

Answer (score -1):

```
// Disabling mouse input without desabling the JSpinner itself
JSpinner spinner = ...;
// set the minimum and maximum values to the current value, 
// thus preventing changes to the spinner's current value
SpinnerNumberModel snm = (SpinnerNumberModel) spinner.getModel();
snm.setMinimum((Integer)spinner.getValue());
snm.setMaximum((Integer)spinner.getValue());
```